# Facebook API couldn't connect to host and timeout errors

Tags: php, facebook, api, timeout

A few days ago I released a beta version of a game on Facebook.
Unfortunately, I'm not so lucky, and in the first most important days of the application when users first use it, they keep getting errors resulting from errors on my PHP Apache server which gets the following errors from Facebook API -

1. couldn't connect to host
2. connect() timed out!

My server runs on a free server I got from Joyent for facebook developers.
I'm not a big expert with web servers so I got no idea if the problems are from my side or Facebook side. 
And how can I fix this problem quickly!

Thanks a lot!

Edit: 
For some reason I forgot about the code samples and error examples -

Here's an example for a simple query against facebook -

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();

$currentID = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id');
```

Here's the error stack trace -

```
couldn't connect to host StackTrace: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /users/home/aagnt2sv/web/public/Facebook/facebook-php-sdk-7d538d3/src/facebook.php
            [line] => 523
            [function] => makeRequest
            [class] => Facebook
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [method] => GET
                            [access_token] => 104269778819|2.AQAKqpIXE0jqFuoU.3600.1311008400.1-785849095|qxtBqmWWRMc_GpM77CK77RbO4YA
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /users/home/aagnt2sv/web/public/Facebook/facebook-php-sdk-7d538d3/src/facebook.php
            [line] => 491
            [function] => _oauthRequest
            [class] => Facebook
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [method] => GET
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [function] => _graph
            [class] => Facebook
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /me?fields=id
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => /users/home/aagnt2sv/web/public/Facebook/facebook-php-sdk-7d538d3/src/facebook.php
            [line] => 444
            [function] => call_user_func_array
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Facebook Object
                                (
                                    [appId:protected] => *censored*
                                    [apiSecret:protected] => *censored*
                                    [session:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [uid] => *censored*
                                            [access_token] => 104269778819|2.AQAKqpIXE0jqFuoU.3600.1311008400.1-785849095|qxtBqmWWRMc_GpM77CK77RbO4YA
                                            [expires] => 1311008400
                                            [sig] => ddf14dcaa953cb64d3f98b0649b60613
                                        )

                                    [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                    [sessionLoaded:protected] => 1
                                    [cookieSupport:protected] => 1
                                    [baseDomain:protected] => 
                                )

                            [1] => _graph
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /me?fields=id
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [file] => /users/home/aagnt2sv/web/public/edamometer/EdamometerWS.php
            [line] => 31
            [function] => api
            [class] => Facebook
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /me?fields=id
                )

        )
```

Thanks again!

Comment: please, clarify with better context and full error messages

Comment: And also post code from the PHP script that's causing these errors

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I updated my post, I hope it's enough.

Comment: Anybody? I'm really stuck on this one... Maybe someone could tell me how can I even begin to debug this problem and see if it's a problem on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was somehow fixed by itself after several days. Maybe it was a temporary problem on my server or on Facebook's servers.

Answer (score 0):

Get user id with

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(

    'appId'  => 'your_app_id',
    'secret' => 'your_app_secret',

));

$user = $fb->getUser();// returns user id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having this problem with my server (using PHP to access the Facebook API), as well. Based upon the nature of the error message, obviously the problem is the connection between my server (running on the Amazon cloud, btw) and Facebook's server(s).

What is throwing me for a loop, though, is that some commands are working properly. That is, attempting to log in with one Facebook token is working fine, while another in causing this error message.

The only reasonable explanation I can come up with is that the Facebook servers are experiencing some sort of temporary hiccup... but even that does a poor job of explaining the problem, since it is somehow tied to the token which is being used. The only way it makes sense is if there's some sort of bug  where Facebook's servers are timing out in processing the specific token I'm giving them...